# Actual image of URL not appearing when clicking submit on form

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

i wanted to create a webpage for creating memes as a fun project.

so far, i am attempting to add a new image element to the body of the document via JS using the url that is entered into the label with input type of url, but the image does not seem to load

//via the code below, i was expecting the actual image of the url to appear on the webpage after appending the image element to the dom but that does no seem to be the case

```
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newImage = document.createElement('img');
    const newImageValue = 
    document.querySelector('#imageLink').value;

    if (newImageValue === '') {
        alert('Please enter a URL');
        return;
    }

    newImage.src = newImageValue;
    newImage.alt = 'Meme Image';
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);
    document.querySelector("imageLink").reset;
});
```

Comment: Works fine here (with the exception of the bad selector on the last line) ~ https://jsfiddle.net/bkdrpc6z/

Comment: @Philisonstrike only form element have the reset functionality and it is a function not a attribute. Input element like text,url doesn't have reset

Comment: @Philisonstrike after seeing your comment/code you made me realize i wasn't actually using the image address itself, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `#` here `document.querySelector("imageLink").reset` when selecting the code which causing the code to break

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  const newImageValue =
    document.querySelector('#imageLink').value;

  if (newImageValue === '') {
    alert('Please enter a URL');
    return;
  }

  newImage.src = newImageValue;
  newImage.alt = 'Meme Image';
  document.body.appendChild(newImage);
  document.querySelector("#imageLink").reset;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="imageLink">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Comment: That wouldn't stop the image loading (see JSFiddle link above)

Comment: @brk only form element have the reset functionality and it is a function not a attribute. Input element like text,url doesn't have reset

Comment: You should have used `form.reset()`